# How to break word if text inside Angular Material button is longer than the width of the button?

Tags: css, angular-material2

How do I make sure that the text inside an Angular Material Button does not overflow, by wrapping the text inside the button. I have tried the following:

#### HTML

```
<div class="cotnainer">
 <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Click me! This is a long text, but I want to to wrap if content is overflowing
 </button>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container{
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: silver;
}
button{
  max-width: 100%;
}

span, .mat-button-wrapper{ // I have tried all of the following options, but it does not work.
  max-width: 100% !important;
  word-break: break-all !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/word-break-button)

**EDIT**
Current result:

[image: Current result]

Desired result: (sorry for my poor image editing skills)
[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can achieve this with this code:

**Hiding:**

```
button {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

**Word Break:**

```
button{
  white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to make the word break as well? Maybe I should be more clear in my question since what I really want is a word break :P I edited the question a little bit because of this, but thanks though

Comment: Great. Thanks. Just what I need ^^ I can also confirm that it works using the `button` -selector, and you don't need the `!important`-flag ;)