# mat-button-toggle not wrapping text

Tags: css, angular, word-wrap

I'm using Angular to display some buttons. I have:

```
.mat-button-toggle {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 3em;
    align-self: center;

    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: #76ff03;
    margin: 0.5em 1em;
}


  <mat-button-toggle 
        *ngFor="let button of buttonsFromApi" 
        id="{{button.id}}" class="problemButton" 
        [disabled]="isButtonDisabled(button.authLevel, button.id)" 
        [checked]="isSelected(button.id)"
        (change)="onButtonClick($event, button.authLevel)">
        {{button.displayName}}
  </mat-button-toggle>
```

Now this just won't wrap the text when I resize the window:

[image]

I've searched the internet and tried `flex-wrap: wrap;` `white-space: normal !important;` `word-wrap: normal;` and all with `!important` yet none of it will work. How can I make sure the text wraps when it overruns the button?

Comment: mat-button-toggle must add to mat-button-toggle-group . Are you doing it?

Comment: No, I don't want to group it. That only allows for 1 button to be pressed at any time, I want to be able to choose multiple ones separately. Plus that groups then visually, too, and that's not what I'm going for.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53497349/5301229

Answer (score 0):

maybe

> overflow-wrap: break-word;

works

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-button-toggle-label-content {
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}
```

solved it!